# Scheduled Tasks django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I built an api that scrapes data from a web. It needs to scraping every hour. How can I manage to program scraping in the background, and doesn't break the requests of the clients?
I apologize for any error gramatical.

Comment: You could write a [django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) and call it with a cronjob or you can use [periodic tasks from celery)[https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html] to name the two most common I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **celery** [Refer Celery Docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)    OR  **django-q** [Checkout Github](https://github.com/Koed00/django-q) , to schedule your task.